# RESTful API Standard when wanting all data under RESOURCE

Tags: api, rest

All `RESTful` examples seem to only consider the `RESOURCE` at that level, e.g.

```
HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/users
HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/users?size=20&page=5
HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/users/123
HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/users/123/address
```

What if I want **users** and **address** to be returned at the same time? E.g. users, address and anything underneath? What is the `RESOURCE` naming standard then? Or is there another approach? E.g.

```
HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/usersALLdata/123
```

Is this correct? Or should it be? `HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/users/123/address/xyz...` Seem an issue if address were to have **xyz** and **abc** tables both as children. Cannot find any guidance on this.

My conclusion is you must add `parameters`. E.g. like so  `https://api.github.com/users/zellwk/repos?sort=pushed`

meaning we would use:

```
HTTP GET http://www.appdomain.com/users/123?ALL=true
```

Looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this unless you decide to follow a standard API building solution. But even those just recommend certain URIs. http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html

Normally I would not care much, just respond with a verbose JSON unless I really want to support some sort of advanced search.